# Fetch a remote branch from another repo

Tags: git, git-remote

I have three machines. On the first one, repo `machine1` has a `develop` branch that is ahead of the `develop` branch of the second machine, `machine2`. `machine2` has fetched it (but not checked out), so it lives as a remote branch `machine1/develop`.

Now `machine2` is online, but not `machine1`, and I'd like to get `machine1/develop` into the third machine `machine3`.

If I do `git fetch machine2` on `machine3`, it will update remote branches for local branches of `machine2`, but won't get its remote branches.

How can I bring `machine1/develop` from `machine2` to `machine3`, without putting `machine1` online? I could stash, checkout, fetch from `machine3`, and unstash, but I believe there's an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git allows you to specify a particular reference via the `refspec` argument: `source:destination`.

In this case the command for copying the remote branch from `machine2` is

```
git fetch machine2 refs/remotes/machine1/develop:refs/remotes/machine1/develop
```